# Bulk delete email from specific address

Tags: linux, centos, dovecot, exim

One of my users had some sort of debug output mailed to a address on my server..

Something "went wrong" and now I have 35000 mails in a inbox. I need to delete those mails, they are all from 1 specific address. The rest of the inbo needs to stay untouched.

How do I achieve this?

Platform: CentOS 5 with DirectAdmin, Dovecot, Exim.

Comment: I might not be able to post a full answer, but do take a look at: http://www.argon.org/~roderick/mbox-purge.html

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Comment: For those wondering about the closure and comment above: This is a remainder of a badly communicated cleanup campaign that was terminated by super-moderator action against a moderator. See [here on Meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8058) for details. Will edit to remove the word "DirectAdmin" and submit for re-opening …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dovecot v.2 has an utility called `doveadm` that allow number of functions.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Expunge

Command

```
doveadm expunge -u jane.doe@example.org savedbefore 2w
```

delete all messages that older than two weeks from jane.doe's mailbox.

If you have dovecot v.1 you have to use system utility `find`:

```
find -E $userdir \
     -type f \
     -iregex ".*(cur|new).*" \
     ! -newerBt "1 month ago" \
     -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks but how to delete all email that is received from one specific email address?

Comment: Managed to do it like this: doveadm expunge -u myaccount@example.com mailbox Inbox FROM spammer@spam.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python just write a quick script using the [poplib](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html)